# Clearing out a Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm having some issues updating a dependency property from a standard property.

If I set the property to null or update it with new data I was under the impression that it would reset the dependency property. However it looks as tho it just piles the new data on top.

Here's a couple of properties / dependency properties I'm using:

**Dependency Properties**

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTableChartProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    ("DataTableChart", typeof(DataTable), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));

public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentElementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
    ("ContentElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MainWindowViewModel));
```

**Standard Properties**

```
public DataTable DataTableChart
{
    get { return (DataTable)this.GetValue(DataTableChartProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(DataTableChartProperty, value); }

public FrameworkElement ContentElement
{
    get { return (FrameworkElement)this.GetValue(ContentElementProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(ContentElementProperty, value); }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in Advance!

This is how I'm setting it for now... for testing...

```
void _bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var loadLog = new LoadLog();
        e.Result = loadLog.LoadCaseLogs(SelectedFiles);
    }

    void _bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTableChart = null;
        ContentElement = null;
        ContentElement = blah;
        DataTableResult = e.Result as DataTable;
        DataTableChart = caseData.LoadUserData(DataTableResult);

        LoadingScreen = false;
    }

public ChartControl blah = new ChartControl();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *it looks as tho it just piles the new data on top*?  Please show us how you are setting the property as that doesn't make much sense.  Calling `DataTableChart = null` should be all you need.

Comment: I tried just setting it to null, didnt work out for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency properties are cleared using the [`ClearValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.clearvalue.aspx) method, setting it to `null` is just setting it to `null`, which is *not* the same.

Comment: so would i do something like, blah.clearvalue(DataTableChart) ?

Comment: @rreeves: Yes, except that you pass the property field, which is `DataTableChartProperty`.